# Using lxml to parse xml with Japanese

Tags: python, mysql, xml, unicode, lxml

I have the following xml document:

```
<package>
    <title>セレニティー (字幕版)</title> 
    ... 
</package>
```

I am using `lxml` to parse the title as follows:

```
node = etree.fromstring(file_contents)
title = node.xpath("//t:title/text()")
title
[u' \u30bb\u30ec\u30cb\u30c6\u30a3\u30fc (\u5b57\u5e55\u7248)']
```

However, when I `INSERT` this into my database using `title.encode(utf-8)`, I get gibberish:

`ã‚»ãƒ¬ãƒ‹ãƒ†ã‚£ãƒ¼ (å­—å¹•ç‰ˆ)`

How would I correctly parse the `title` here (セレニティー (字幕版)), so I can do an `INSERT` of the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your MySQL instance is set up to store Unicode as UTF-8 as well.

Comment: `SET GLOBAL init_connect='SET NAMES utf8';`

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a problem in lxml itself to me, they assume everybody will use ASCII/Latin-1 by default, which is stupid. Even trying to run the parser in UTF-8 may return errors to you, try calling the parser like this:

> parser = etree.HTMLParser(encoding='shift-jis')

Shift-JIS is still the most common charset for pages in Japanese, as far as I can see. My Python/lxml module http://github.com/caio1982/Amazon-Wishlist works with Japanese pages using the above.